# Meteor page is loading incrementaly somehow, and very slow

Tags: meteor

I have a rather simple page with not so much data (about 20k documents in total), and it's VERY sluggish (complete load takes about 30-60 seconds). And what intrigues me most is that data appears gradually on page. Why is that? And why it's so slow?

Here is the page .jade file (it basically returns just order name and order's position name):

```
table(class="ui celled table")
thead
  tr
    th Order name
    th Position name
tbody
  each customerOrders
    tr
      td {{name}}
      td
    each customerOrderPositionModified
      tr
        td
        td #{name}
```

The corresponding .js file is empty.

The router.js file (for Iron Router) is this:

```
this.route('/buyingList/:supplierUuid', {
data: function() {
  var supplierUuid = this.params.supplierUuid;
  var retOrd = [];
  _.each(orders.find({checked: true}, {name: 1, "customerOrderPosition.name": 1, "customerOrderPosition.quantity": 1, "customerOrderPosition.supplierUuid": 1 }).fetch(), function (order) {
    var ret = [];
    _.each(order.customerOrderPosition, function (pos) {
      var good = Goods.findOne({uuid: pos.goodUuid}, {name:1, supplierUuid:1});
      if (good) {
        if (good.supplierUuid == supplierUuid){
          var company = Companies.findOne({uuid: good.supplierUuid}, {name: 1, uuid: 1});
          var tt = {name: good.name, quantity: pos.quantity, companyName: (company ? company.name : "")};
          ret.push(tt);
        }
      }
    });
    if (ret.length > 0) {
      order.customerOrderPositionModified = ret;
      retOrd.push(order);
    }
  });
  return { customerOrders: retOrd };
},
name: 'buyingList'
});
```

The sizes of the collections:

- Orders: 5k documents
- Goods: 10k documents
- Companies: 5k documents

The number of checked orders (which are returned in first query) is about 30.

What am I doing wrong? Or meteor is supposed to be so slow? I doubt it.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Are all of these documents published to the client (is autopublish still on)? Meteor can be really slow if more than a few thousand docs are published at a time.

Comment: Autopublish is off, but all these documents are published, the whole collections. So, should I add parameters to publications so only relevant documents will be published?

Comment: Yes absolutely. In general, your goal should be to publish only the subset of the database that you need to satisfy the UI requirements of the route your are on.

Comment: Thanks, will try that tomorrow. I just thought that router code is being executed on server, so the client only receives the ready data, the size if which is quite small.

Comment: The router is actually executed on the client.

Comment: @DavidWeldon your suggestion was right, after I removed the unneded data from publication, it went much smoother. Also, publish-composite helped.

Comment: Okay - I'll move this to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**summary**

Meteor can be really slow if more than a few thousand docs are published at a time.

**recommendation**

Modify your publishers to accept the necessary parameters to publish only the subset of the database that you need to satisfy the UI requirements of the route your are on.